# PayPal REST API: Setting landing page to 'BILLING' when creating order always returns link to login page instead of card fields form

Tags: paypal

When creating an order request in PayPal REST API they say there is a possibility to set 'landing_page' field in 'application_context' object to 'BILLING' to get a link for credit or debit card payment form. Unfortunately when I use 'approve' link from 'links' array from order response it always opens login form. What should I do to get a link to credit/debit card form when using 'BILLING' setting of landing page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current PayPal checkout integrations don't use redirects, and that parameter is no longer used from what I've seen

Instead of redirecting, use the JS SDK for the approval flow. [Here is a demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) that fetches to a backend for creating and capturing the order with the API.

With this integration, the "Debit or Credit Card" button is present and will open inline on your own site.